# Clarification over lvalue , rvalue behaviour of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;

    printf("\n address of initialized pointer p: %u \n", p);
    p = &(*p);
    printf("\n modified address of initialized pointer p:%u value:%d valuez address: %d \n", p, *p, &(*p));

    return 0;
}
```

the code outputs:-

address of initialized pointer p: 3221221820

modified address of initialized pointer p:3221221820 value:10 valuez address: -1073745476

Why is "&(*p)", behaving differently when used in a assignment statement and in a printf statement ?

**Update**
Sorry, just format specifier mistake in printf ;).Thanks for the replies and pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using incorrect format specifier in printf. Using `%d` for printing addresses won't work. Use `%p` rather. [`%u` for printing address isn't correct either.]

[This](http://www.ideone.com/PwWAL) works as per expectation.

Comment: What difference does it make between %p and %u ??

Comment: `%u` is for printing unsigned integers, `%p` is for pointers.

Comment: Thanks Prasoon, one more doubt, when i use %p i get 0x7fbffff1bc, but when i convert the value printed by %u - 3221221820 to hex i'm getting only bffff1bc. So what is this extra 0x7f appended when i use %p ?

Comment: @Saran : The value is represented in hexadecimal format in that case. Hence that `0x`.

Comment: @Saran, pointers and `unsigned` might not have the same width.

Comment: @Prasoon, not just "0x" is added as prefix but, "0x7f" is added as prefix !!! whats this 7f ?

Comment: @Jens, ok so the unsigned might have smaller width and hence missing the 7f is it ? so the value printed by %p is only correct , am i right ?

Comment: @Saran : Part of the address( represented in [hexadecimal format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) )

Answer (score 1):

The standard format specifier for pointers is `%p`. For safety you should always explicitly cast the pointer to `(void*)` in your call to `printf`. Any other format specifier is not guaranteed to work with pointer values.

e.g.

```
printf("p: %p; *p: %d; &(*p): %p \n", (void*)p, *p, (void*)&(*p));
```

The difference you are seeing is simply that the first format specifier is `%u` which prints the pointer value as an unsigned integer and the second time you are using `%d` which prints it as a signed integer.

Comment: If the value is already a pointer, what difference does casting it to a `void*` make?  I can see the problem with leaving it as is in C++ (inheritance and operator overloading can cause issues there), but what makes it dangerous in C?

Comment: @cHao: Although not common, pointers to different types can have different representations in C. The `%p` format specifier requires the corresponding argument to have type "pointer to `void`" so if the variable you have is a pointer to something else then strictly you need to convert it to meet the requirements of `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

`%d` instead of `%u` when you are trying to print the address second time.

Note the change in bold in the modified source below:

> printf("\n modified address of
>   initialized pointer p:%u value:%d
>   valuez address: **%u** \n", p, *p,
>   &(*p));

Most notably you should use %p for printing out a pointer value instead of %u as already pointed out in [another answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138244/clarification-over-lvalue-rvalue-behaviour-of-pointers-in-c/6138277#6138277).